# dynamic allocation of array of pointers to structs

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, malloc

I have 2 structs in my program.

linked list of id's, and a WORD

```
typedef struct related
{
    int id;
    struct related* next;
} RELATED;

typedef struct word
{
    int id;
    char name[NAME_LEN];
    RELATED *related;
} WORD;
```

i want to hold an array of WORD's and i want it to be dynamic.

I have 2 pointers to words:

```
WORD* word1;
WORD* word2;
```

with values.

when i am tryin to dynamically allocate it in this way:

```
WORD** arr = (WORD**)malloc(sizeof(WORD*)*10)  // to hold 10 words
```

and trying to add a word to an array, the first one is added properly, but the second one run over the first one:

```
arr[0] = word1;
arr[1] = word2;
```

when i am defining the array this way:

```
WORD* arr[40];
```

the same add of words works just fine

```
arr[0] = word1;
arr[1] = word2;
```

can't quite find the right way of this dynamic allocation.. thnx for help!

Comment: [Seems to work fine for me?](http://codepad.org/hkAq33CV) (Yes, not free'ing memory, fine for this purpose though)

Comment: It should work fine, can you share your program code?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than

```
// arr as pointer to pointer to WORDS
WORDS** arr = (WORDS**)malloc(sizeof(WORDS*)*10);
```

Allocate

```
// arr as pointer to WORDS
WORDS* arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * 10);  // WORDS *, not WORDS **
```

1. [C gibberish ↔ English](http://cdecl.org/) may be useful.
2. Casting the result of `malloc()` is discouraged in C.
3. Consider the `type *p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * N);` style.  Easier to maintain and less error prone IMO.

Comment: What is not clear is the comment "to hold 10 words".  Your `malloc()` holds 10 pointers to WORDS.  Further, Are you simple wanting to copy pointers `word1, word2` or the date they point to?

Comment: @Andrey Chasovski How did you determine "but the second one run over the first"?  With your edited info, it _appears_ you are doing things right - need more info.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any issue with malloc() and using pointer to pointer of WORD as array. One thing I can point out that, you have not allocated memory for word1 and word2 they hold a garbage address. Same garbage address is being assigned to arr[0] and arr[1]. If you upload complete code, it will help in finding out exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snippet for dynamic memory allocation for 2D array :

Let 'm' and 'n' are dimensions of an array .

```
WORDS** arr = (WORDS**)malloc(sizeof(WORDS*)*m);

for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++)

{

    for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)

    {

         arr[i] = (WORDS*)malloc(sizeof(WORDS)*n);

    }

}
```